# Postgres - timestamp with timezone from json

Tags: json, postgresql, timestamp

Is it possible to get a recordset from json and keep the time zone for the dates?

If I do

```
SELECT * from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"date": "2016-01-04T13:42:32+03:00"}]')
AS x ("date" TIMESTAMP);
```

it returns `2016-01-04 13:42:32`

I tried with `AS x ("date" TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE);` but the syntax is not valid.

If it is not possible to have the timezone, I'd like to have at least the timestamp with the correct UTC time -> `10:42:32` in my example

Comment: All you need is just some more space. Try `AS x ("date" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)` (another possible alias for this type is `timestamptz`).

Comment: Oops, I read the doc too quickly... Thanks!